# Flutter: display YouTube videos from API provider

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-api

I'm using the API with provider for fetching data from database, and I have a list of YouTube video links that I want to use for presenting the videos. But I can't put the list of links in `_controllers` because of the error:

> The instance member 'serviceProvider' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

This is my code:

```
static List<YoutubePlayerController> _controllers =
   ['uEZAT3YJvDw', 'zMPfxQunIRw', 'uEZAT3YJvDw'] //I want to replace this line with the api list of links
          .map<YoutubePlayerController>(
            (videoId) => YoutubePlayerController(
              initialVideoId: videoId,
              flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
                autoPlay: false,
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList();

ListView.separated(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: YoutubePlayer(
                              key: ObjectKey(_controllers[index]),
                              controller: _controllers[index],
                              actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                              bottomActions: [
                                CurrentPosition(),
                                ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
                                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                RemainingDuration(),
                                FullScreenButton(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: _controllers.length,
                      )

class HomeDatum {
  HomeDatum({
    this.attachment,
  });
  var attachment; // this json carry the link

  factory HomeDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HomeDatum(
        attachment: json["attachment"],
      );}

Future<dynamic> getVideosList() async {

    http.Response response = await http
        .get(url, headers: headers);

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (responseData['status'] == 1) {
      _homeDatum = [];
      responseData['data'].forEach((element) {
        _homeDatum.add(HomeDatum.fromJson(element));
      });
      results = true;
    } 
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return results;
  }
```

Comment: YOu can add your video id's in one array and then passed it to your `YoutubePlayerController`

Comment: can you show me how to do it please ?

Comment: On which page you are playing videos? on same page or second page?

Comment: on the same page in the list.seperate which i mention in my code

Comment: Okay, i create same but on first i show listview and then passed particular video id on second page then play video by using `YoutubePlayer`

Comment: no problem so can you learn me how you did  it ?

Comment: Yes, On the first screen I called API, and from this API I stored the video id's in `List _controllers = [];` by `_controllers.add("videoid")`. and after that simply created a listview by using this `_controllers` And show all data. Once user click on particular video get that video id and send to next page

Comment: i will try this method and i will back to you soon , thanks for you

Comment: and on second page first initialize `YoutubePlayerController _controller;` this and then in initState() added    `_controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: widget.url,
    );`  and then simply play video in body part like this `Container(
          child: YoutubePlayer(
            controller: _controller,
          ),
        ),`

Comment: The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class. )this error appear when i added _controllers.add("videoid");

Comment: You can change the name

Comment: i did it but still the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227640/discussion-between-shubham-narkhede-and-mariam-younes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling API and you want to get data from API and show data on same page. First you need to initialize the

```
  final List _controllers = [];   // This for your video id's
  static List<YoutubePlayerController> _controllersYoutube; // this is your YouTube Controller data
  var videoData; // This for store API response
```

Then you need to create API call method and set your id's to `_controllersYoutube`

```
  Future getVideos() async {
    var url = "$baseUrl/api/videos";  // Your API
    var response = await http.get(url);
    videoData = json.decode(response.body);
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        for (var myAllData in videoData) {
          _controllers.add(myAllData['youtube_video_id']);
        }
        _controllersYoutube = _controllers.map<YoutubePlayerController>((videoId) {

         `// eodZS9Wkab0  yc9JIvamDm4  9Ty_qqvhiI4  Te862nM7mJ0 I'm getting this id's from API`

          return YoutubePlayerController(
            initialVideoId: videoId,
            flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
              autoPlay: false,
            ),
          );
        }).toList();
        // loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

And then simply create a UI for show listview with YouTube videos like below

```
     body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 150,
            child: YoutubePlayer(
              key: ObjectKey(_controllersYoutube[index]),
              controller: _controllersYoutube[index],
              actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              bottomActions: [
                CurrentPosition(),
                ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                RemainingDuration(),
                FullScreenButton(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: _controllers.length,
      )
```

I hope this answer will work for you.